# Faced the issue with creating/editing Named Credentials

Tags: error, namedcredentials

Let's say there is need to create new or edit existing Named Credentials entry. But every time I get an error like 'Something went wrong getting your credentials. Try again, or contact Salesforce Customer Support for help.'

Moreover when i try to use existing one  i get an exception like
`IdentityHash failure when getting keyId: 02G0M000000od0q of type CREDENTIAL for Context Org: 00D9A00000094ES .This is not expected. This may indicate that the Context org is accessing another's encryption keys (which is very bad).`

Is it possible to find out the reasons of this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and/or contact Salesforce Customer Support for assistance.

Comment: seems like it's related to particular org

Comment: You should open a case. This is not expected behavior.